# Composer: how to overwrite the dependency of a dependency with my own fork?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I use the following dependency: https://github.com/furqansiddiqui/erc20-php,
which requires itself https://github.com/furqansiddiqui/ethereum-rpc.

However, the latter has an Issue which I have solved in my own fork: https://github.com/itinance/ethereum-rpc/

Now I like composer to install my own fork and not the original repository.

I tried:

```
{
    "name": "test-erc20",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:itinance/ethereum-rpc.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "furqansiddiqui/erc20-php": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

But it still is installing the original library and not my fork.

I also tried patches:

```
{
    "name": "test/erc-20",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:itinance/ethereum-rpc.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "furqansiddiqui/erc20-php": "dev-master",
        "netresearch/composer-patches-plugin": "^1.2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,

    "extra": {
        "patches": {
            "furqansiddiqui/ethereum-rpc": [
                {
                    "title": "Fix SSL",
                    "url": "https://github.com/itinance/ethereum-rpc/commit/55774ee14dd90fbcc85220d28bc77ecf97a6ced5.patch"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But they won't be applied.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried removing vendor dir and run `composer clearcache` (or removing package from .composer/cache if you don't wan't to delete all cache) and run `composer update` ?

Comment: yes. And even removed vender and composer.lock and all this